# Android buildTypes multiple debug modes

Tags: android, android-build-type

I have three build types, and I am trying to get the `staging` build type to run but I am getting the following error:

> **Error:** The apk for your currently selected variant (app-staging-unsigned.apk) is not signed. Please specify a signing configuration for the variant (staging).

Is there a way for me to run `staging` without signing, as like a second debug?

```
android {
     buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER", '"dev.gamesmart.com"'
        }
        staging {
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER", '"staging.gamesmart.com"'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER", '"gamesmart.com"'
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
android {
     buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER", '"dev.gamesmart.com"'
        }

        staging.initWith(buildTypes.debug)

        staging {
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER", '"staging.gamesmart.com"'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER", '"gamesmart.com"'
        }
    }   
}
```

This says "have `staging` start as a clone of `debug`, then we'll modify from there", so `staging` should apply the `debug` signing config.

Comment: What a simple solution! Thank you!